# How to perform an action if an element exist on the page in GEB?

Tags: geb

I was working on a dynamic page. Is there any way that I can do something like below in GEB?

```
if ( $('#hideAnnouncement').isDisplayed() ){
    waitFor{ $('.icon').click()}
    waitFor{ !$('#hideAnnouncement').isDisplayed()}
}
```

Any help or suggestion would be really helpful!

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, can you please clarify? The above looks like a completely valid Geb code.

Comment: is it really a valid block of code? It was not working with me. Okay, thanks for the comment. I will double check and will let you know soon. Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't know; I might be getting error because of something else. I wish you would put the comment 4 days back! However, it worked fine. Thanks so much!

Comment: A question like this really needs the error you are getting to be specified. Maybe you are attempting to call isDisplayed on an empty Navigator. If so use a negated isEmpty.

Answer (score -1):

First of all if you are using Geb, you should really use the Page Object content template.

Second, that is valid code.

```
if($('#hideAnnouncement').isDisplayed()) { //if the #hideAnnouncement element is displayed
    #('.icon').click() //clicks without unnecessarily waiting
    waitFor{!$('#hideAnnouncement').isDisplayed()} //waits for the #hideAnnouncement element to disappear
}
```